# Testing transaction fee movements

Tags: runtime, transactions, testing, mock

I am attempting to build some tests that initiate and validate transaction fee movements. The problem is that I seem unable to initiate transaction fees in a mock runtime at all. I suspect I am missing something fundamental about how mocks/tests are using `UncheckedExtrinsic` and `SignedExtra`, so any help would be appreciated!

My release version of the runtime works fine to charge tx fees and transfer them to the appropriate pallet. I implemented `OnUnbalanced` and a custom fee splitter in the `CurrencyAdapter` of `pallet_transaction_payment`.

I moved the same fee splitter mechanism over to my mock runtime and overrode the standard Unchecked extrinsic code `MockUncheckedExtrinsic`, but seem unable to trigger transaction fees to even be taken in the mock runtime. Here is what is not working so far:

```
// type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
// type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;

// An attempt to test charging tx fees in mocks that failed :(
pub type SignedExtra = (
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Test>,
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Test>,
);
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic = sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<AccountId, Call, (), SignedExtra>;
pub type Block = sp_runtime::generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;

frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        MyPallet: my_pallet::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about the transaction fees do you want to test, and what is your mock configuration of this pallet? Have you looked at and played around with the tests found in the transaction payment pallet? https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs#L801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @kianenigma and @shawn-tabrizi pointing me in the right direction, I realized that to do what I'm looking for I just need to call `pre_dispatch` and `post_dispatch` manually on the call.

In addition to adjusting the the mock as I showed above in the original question, I wrote a simple call wrapper to take the transaction fees on the calls I'd like to check. I provide it here in case anyone else is interested:

```rust
use crate::Call as PalletCall;
use pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment;

fn fee_call_wrapper(call: PalletCall<Test>, from: AccountId) {
    let pallet_pre = free_balance(&MyPallet::account_id());
    let from_pre = balance(&from); // Don't care about reserves for tx fee tests

    let call: <Test as frame_system::Config>::Call = Call::MyPallet(call);
    let info = call.get_dispatch_info();
    let len = call.encode().len();
    let pre_d = ChargeTransactionPayment::<Test>::from(0).pre_dispatch(&from, &call.clone(), &info, len).expect("pre_dispatch error");
    let post_result = call.dispatch(Origin::signed(from.clone())).expect("dispatch failure");
    let actual_fee = TransactionPayment::compute_actual_fee(len.try_into().unwrap(), &info, &post_result, 0);
    assert_ok!(ChargeTransactionPayment::<Test>::post_dispatch(
        Some(pre_d),
        &info,
        &post_result,
        len,
        &Ok(())
    ));

    //Check fees
    let split = (80,20);
    let pallet_fee = actual_fee * split.0 / 100;
    assert_eq!(free_balance(&MyPallet::account_id()), pallet_fee + pallet_pre );
    assert_eq!(balance(&from), from_pre - actual_fee);
```

Which can then be called like so:

```rust
#[test]
fn do_something_with_tx_fees_taken_works() {
    ExtBuilder::default().build().execute_with(|| {
        let call = PalletCall::do_something{...};
        fee_call_wrapper(call, ALICE);

        // Do other checks here...
    });
}
```

Note that this is just a simple fee splitter, taking 80% to the MyPallet account.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the reason is for splitting?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup actually looks correct. What you have to do next is to make sure you call into the exact same functions as a real runtime when you execute a transaction.

In reality, this happens in `frame-executive` and in [`fn apply_extrinsic`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/9428b0ea492d405f320753fcd93bc59ebb3bf33b/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L434). To mirror that into your test setup:

1. You probably want to skip signature verification, so you need a stub that will naively concert `UncheckedExtrinsic` to `CheckedExtrinsic` for you.

```rust
fn check(uxt: UncheckedExtrinsic) -> CheckedExtrinsic {
  // should just map the fields one to one. 
}
```

2. Then, you can imitate what the executive does:

```rust
fn dispatch(uxt: UncheckedExtrinsic) {
  let xt = check(uxt); 
  let encoded_len = xt.encoded_size();
  let dispatch_info = xt.get_dispatch_info();
  let r = Applyable::apply::<_>(xt, &dispatch_info, encoded_len)?;
}
```

Some other relevant types implementations:

1. [`Applyable`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Applyable.html).
2. [`Checkable`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Checkable.html).
3. [`GetDispatchInfo`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/weights/trait.GetDispatchInfo.html)

Note that you have opted to use the real `generic::UncheckedExtrinsic` in your example, but you can probably do it with [`TestXt`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/testing/struct.TestXt.html) as well.